# Eclipse includes not updating after gcc update

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I recently updated my GCC version from gcc4.2 to gcc4.8 on mac os x 10.6. However, the includes tab under my C++ project in eclipse still list /usr/include/c++/4.2.1, /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward and /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/x86_64-apple-darwin-10. How do I update my includes to use the newer gcc4.8 versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem before. Here's my solution.

Goto your eclipse workspace folder, delete .metadata folder and restart eclipse.

No idea if there are any side effect. Take your own risk about it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the wrong infomation is stored in workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core/language.settings.xml

Replace all occurences of x.y by z.t where x.y is the old version number and z.t the new version number.

Be careful, you will find 2 occurences x.y.p that you will need to change into z.t.q

z.q.t is obtained by calling gcc --version.
In my case I get "gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1"
Then z.t.q = 4.8.1